How to add .0 to a numeric variable in SAS to selected values only and resulted variable should also be numeric? No custom formats to be used
I am trying to add .0 to a numeric variable to a subset of values. The expected output variable should also be numeric. here is the sample dataset.
    data test;
     a=0; output;
     a=1; output;
     a=2; output;
     a=3; output;
     a=95; output;
    run;

.0 is to be added only where a=0,1,2,3 and NOT 95. So the expected output is:
0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,95
No custom formats are to be created, this is a restriction for my data. Please assist.
Thank You.

Use the 3.1 format. This allocates 3 total spaces for the number and a single number after the decimal. If it cannot fit all of the values, it will reduce/round the number displayed. Since 95.0 is 4 spaces and we've asked for a maximum of 3, it will remain as 95.
data test;
    format a 3.1;
    a=0; output;
    a=1; output;
    a=2; output;
    a=3; output;
    a=95; output;
run;

Or:
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify test;
        format a 3.1;
quit;

a
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
95


Many thanks, I have been using 5.1 but never thought of 3.1 format. :)

@Rhythm You might notice this NOTE: which some might find disquieting.
NOTE: At least one W.D format was too small for the number to be printed. The decimal may be shifted by the "BEST" format.
